# Python Click: Multiple Key Value Pair Arguments

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using the Python Click library for my command-line interface. I'd like to have a command that takes multiple key value pairs. I'm flexible on the api. For example

```
my_cli my_command FOO=1 BAR=2
```

or maybe

```
my_cli my_command FOO 1 BAR 2
```

or even

```
my_cli my_command {"FOO": 1, "BAR": 2}
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Click?

Comment: Is it acceptable to just ask click to give you unlimited arguments, then `my_command` will get them all as a single tuple (like `*args` in regular Python) and iterate over them and pair them up?

Comment: If it _is_ acceptable, see my answer. If it isn't—e.g., you need to take advantage of the built-in way Click handles options in a way that can accept `--foo=1`, `--foo:1`, `--foo 1`, but need arbitrary option-like-things and without `--` prefixes—then I think it's impossible. You could write a new [`Parameter`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#parameters) subclass that handles these, but that's explicitly not supported, and may be broken by even minor updates to `click`.

Comment: One last thing: You might want to consider submitting [a feature request](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues) (if there isn't one there already). It might help to refer to it as, say, "`dd`-style operands", and come up with other common examples that are equivalent to what you want, both to make your request seem more useful/normal, and to provide a good test case if someone does decide to implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is basically the same thing you'd do with a regular Python function where you wanted an API like this.

Take a single parameter that groups the variable-length stream of arguments into a tuple. Then, what you do depends on whether you want separate arguments:

```
>>> def func(*args):
...     d = dict(zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))
...     print(d)
>>> func('FOO', 1, 'BAR', 2)
{'FOO': 1, 'BAR': 2}
```

… or combined `key:value` arguments:

```
>>> def func(*args):
...     d = dict(arg.split(':') for arg in args)
...     print(d)
```

This one is a bit hacky to use, because in Python, arguments aren't just space-separated words, but bear with me on that:

```
>>> func('FOO:1', 'BAR:2')
{'FOO': 1, 'BAR': 2}
```

---

The `click` equivalent for the first looks like this:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def my_command(args):
    d = dict(zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))
    click.echo(d)
```

(Obviously you can stick that in a `click.group`, etc., just like any other command.)

And now:

```
$ ./clicky.py FOO 1 BAR 2
{'FOO': 1, 'BAR': 2}
```

And the second looks like this:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def my_command(args):
    d = dict(arg.split(':') for arg in args)
    click.echo(d)
```

And notice that now, using it is not hacky at all, because to your shell, arguments are just words separated by spaces:

```
$ ./clicky.py FOO:1 BAR:2
{'FOO': 1, 'BAR': 2}
```

---

What if you want to handle both `KEY=VALUE` and `KEY:VALUE`? Then you just have to write something slightly more complicated than `arg.split(':')`. And you'll probably want some better error handling too. But that should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 9):

The same is possible with options instead of arguments, see [Tuples as Multi Value Options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/options/#tuples-as-multi-value-options) in combination with [Multiple Options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/options/#multiple-options).

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--dict", "-d", "mydict", type=(str, int), multiple=True)
def cli(mydict):
    d = dict(mydict)
    click.echo(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Example:

```
$ python3 ./clickexample.py -d hello 1 -d foo 2 -d baz 3
{'hello': 1, 'foo': 2, 'baz': 3}
```

Comment: the good solution! but sadly ``-d foo=2`` dont work

Comment: hmm i'll need to look at this, but maybe you can put the dict(mydict) operation into a callback ?

Comment: @ThomasDecaux well the treatment would have to be different since "foo=2" would be treated by the shell as a single string

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in click using a [callback](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/options/#callbacks-for-validation) like so:

```py
def _attributes_to_dict(
    ctx: click.Context, attribute: click.Option, attributes: tuple[str, ...]
) -> dict[str, str]:
    """Click callback that converts attributes specified in the form `key=value` to a
    dictionary"""
    result = {}
    for arg in attributes:
        k, v = arg.split("=")
        if k in result:
            raise click.BadParameter(f"Attribute {k!r} is specified twice")
        result[k] = v

    return result


@click.command()
@click.option(
    "-a",
    "--attributes",
    help="Attributes in the form key=value. Can be specified multiple times.",
    multiple=True,
    callback=_attributes_to_dict,
)
def cli(attributes: dict[str, str]):
    print(attributes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Usage:

```bash
>>> python cli.py -a key=value -a other_key=other_value
{'key': 'value', 'other_key': 'other_value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [this custom click type](https://gist.github.com/welel/9cf860dd3f4d3e09f9b4305878b3a04e) because I needed a lot of custom options, including list, int, str.

```bash
... command --param='page=1; name=Items; rules=1, 2, three; extra=A,;'
```

```py
{'page': 1, 'name': 'Items', 'rules': [1, 2, 'three'], 'extra': ['A']}
```

**Usage:**

```py
>>> @click.option("--param", default=None, type=DictParamType())
... def command(param):
...     ...
```

**Example:**

```py
>>> param_value = 'page=1; name=Items; rules=1, 2, three; extra=A,;'
>>> DictParamType().convert(param_value, None, None)
{'page': 1, 'name': 'Items', 'rules': [1, 2, 'three'], 'extra': ['A']}
```